# asp.net MVC saving relative path in database as not the full path

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, uploadify

asp.net MVC saving relative path in database as

```
~/Content/Uploads/11thMay.jpg
```

not the full path as

```
D:/Projects/HRMV2/CubicHRMWeb/Content/Uploads/11thMay.jpg
```

I wanted to save relative path but in DB full path was being saved.

How can I do it?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is "How to save as full path", please try this

```
string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/Company/LogoFiles"), filename);
```

If your question is "How to save as relative path", please try this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(HttpPostedFileBase myFile)
{
    string filename = myFile.FileName;
    string relativeFileName = "~/Content/Uploads/" + filename;// relative path

    return View();
}
```

Comment: No i wanted to save relative path but in DB full path was being saved

Answer (score 0):

this code doesn't allow to save the relative path, when you try it, the totality of filename is setted and not just the filename.if you insert a breakpoint at this point, you must obtain a thing like

```
   "/content/Uploads/C:Document/Picture/father.jpeg"
```

and not the relative path which you will want it like

```
  "/content/Uploads/father.jpeg"
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to save the relative path of a document , you ought to use the getfilename property of system.io as show in the below example.

I suppose that you want to do it in the post method of your controller which contains a model or httppostedfilebase
in my example, i have a model with httppostedfilebase property named imagefichier, so you can get the  document name by doing this

```
 var lefilename =   System.IO.Path.GetFileName(model.imagefichier.FileName);
//Suppose that you want to save it in your root web file
 //like ~/Images/Administrateur/leilename,you can do it like this
    string cheminbdd = "~/Images/Administrateur/" + lefilename;
  //it is cheminbdd that you can save in your database as your relative path
```